# starting the activity is taking very long time

Tags: android, web-services, dynamic, android-asynctask

After calling the intent it was taking a long time to start the activity and application is a dynamic application. I am connecting to the server and retrieving the information from the server. I want activity to be started immediately, and I tried with `AsyncTask` without any result.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Data> arraydata;
    private Data data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //finish();
                new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
                /*Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLParsingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);*/
            }

        },3000);
    }
    private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

       int progress_status;
         TextView txt_percentage=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
               // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
               super.onPreExecute();
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              //  Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLParsingActivity.class);
                //MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                progress_status = 0;
                txt_percentage.setText("downloading 0%");

              }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLParsingActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

          /* while(progress_status<100){

                progress_status += 5;

                publishProgress(progress_status);
                SystemClock.sleep(200);

               }*/
           //Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLParsingActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
return null;

    }
    @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        ProgressBar progressBar=new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this);
       progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
       txt_percentage.setText("downloading " +values[0]+"%");

      }
    @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
      /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txt_percentage.setText("download complete");
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLParsingActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);*/

      }

    }

}
```

From my Main activity I would like to move to `XMLParsingActivity` and it consists of the `ListViews` that consists of the xml data retrieved from the server. In XMLParsingActivity I an using the dynamic information.

**XMLParsingActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        //mCustomView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, null);

        //final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        //bar.setCustomView(mCustomView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //arraydata=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ary");
        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        arraydata =new ArrayList<Data>();
         Uri="http://vegaentertain.com/android/list.xml";
          // Toast.makeText(this, "Loading List.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
}

    private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

           int progress_status;
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                   // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
                   super.onPreExecute();
                  // ProgressBar bar=new ProgressBar(XMLParsingActivity.this);
                 //  bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  Toast.makeText(XMLParsingActivity.this, "Loading List.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             XMLParser parser=new XMLParser();

                String xml=parser.getXmlFromUri(Uri);
                Document doc=parser.getDomElement(xml);
                NodeList nodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("actress");

                for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
                    data=new Data();
                    Element e=(Element)nodes.item(i);
                    data.setName(parser.getValue(e,"name"));
                    data.setDate(parser.getValue(e,"date"));
                    data.setImageurl(parser.getValue(e,"image-url"));
                    arraydata.add(data);
                }


    return null;

        }
        @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(values);



          }
        @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
            listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(arraydata,XMLParsingActivity.this));
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new ShowAsyncTask(arg2).execute();

                }
            });

          }
        private class ShowAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
            int pos;
            public ShowAsyncTask(int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                pos=arg2;
            }
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                   // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
                   super.onPreExecute();

                     connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(XMLParsingActivity.this);
                    connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server...");
                    connectionProgressDialog.show();
                    }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return null;
            }
             protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                   // downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.show();
                }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Intent i=new Intent(XMLParsingActivity.this,List.class);
                i.putExtra("pos",pos);
                XMLParsingActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }

        }
        }

        }
```

Can some give me suggestions.

Comment: First off, remove the delay from the onCreate method, you're just delaying the splash screen from appearing because of that.

Comment: after removing that one also taking the same time

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no need of AsyncTask in the MainActivity.java. (note: you can't call intent from doInbackground of AsyncTask()). By seeing your code i beleive it is just a splash screen. in that case use the following:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {

   super.onStart();

    Handler handler = new Handler();

       // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

                  //code written here will execute after 2000ms(2 seconds)
                  // write your intent to move from MainActivity.this to XMLParsingActivity.class

       }, 2000); 
     }
   }
   ```
2. It is taking time because you have called "new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();" in onCreate() method of XMLParsingActivity class. Since it requires to send a request to server, get the response, parse and update the UI it is obvious to take time.
3. What you can do is, call that AsyncTask in onStart() method. Display a ProgressDialog initially to let the user know that something is in progress. And finally in onPostExecute() just set the visibility of the ProgressBar to GONE and make the visibility of the content VISIBLE.

Comment: ofcourse it take time but it was taking some what long time is there any possibility to reduce the time

Comment: i have removed the async task in main activity

Comment: is it a live server or a local server? it depends on your network speed, the load on server to process requests and all. if it is taking same amount of time while using local server, then you need to optimize your code.

Comment: That is something which you have to work out yourself. I can't help you with that without knowing your code. 

Use AsyncTask only when you are performing network operations, or some complex algorithms which might take a long time to complete blocking the UI.

Comment: it was taking nearly 30sec of time to open the activity]